# Refresh Combo Box query after another

Tags: ms-access, combobox

I have two combo boxes on a form. One for start date and one for end date. When a start date is selected it limits the end dates to those greater than the selected start date. This works correctly but how do i get the end date query to refresh when a new start date is selected? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the row source for the end date combobox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could use endDateBox.Requery after you limit the values.

Answer (score 2):

Pocket is correct, though it may be beneficial to add

```
Me.EndDateBox = Null
Me.EndDateBox.Requery
```

assuming that your query in some way restricts the dates allowed. Adding the "Null" ensures that any entry that WAS in there is no longer; the requery has the possibility of having the correct query with an old (incorrect) input. This forces the user to enter a new, implicitly correct value in the combo box.

Comment: It rather depends on *how* the end date is limited. It is quite possible that the row source is set at runtime, in which case a requery is not going to help.

Comment: It should work regardless; it forces the Row Source to be refreshed.. if it does not contain any dynamic, refreshable material, then he would need to edit it using VBA code similar to `Me.EndDateBox.RowSource = " New row source stuff "` followed by my above. he also mentions "end date query".. implying something dynamic.